# Cognito migration flow does not return scopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying out moving my our user base to AWS Cognito, and I am following this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/) to do it.

I managed to make it work, but I am having an issue with scopes...
I am trying to use the `Resource Servers` and `Allowed Custom Scopes` features, but when I follow that tutorial, the access token always gets a single sope:

```
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
```

Which I actually don't want my users to have.
I tried to use the resource servers features without the InitiateAuth flow and it worked, but that way I cannot migrate my users without forcing them to re-enter their password.

Am I missing something? can it be done?

**Edit**: Example for a scope which worked when I used the `client_credentials` flow (which does not fit my use case)

```
"scope": "test2/test.read http://localhost:3001/test"
```

Hope it helps to understand what I am trying to get